# R: Subset list of data frames by number of columns?

Tags: r, subset, lapply

I have a problem to subset my list containing data frames by simple condition - number of columns.

here is my dataset:

```
d1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=c(rep(2006, times=4),NA), cc=c(1:5))
d2<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(2007, 2007, NA, NA, 2007))
```

my list:

```
ls1<-list(d1, d2)
```

**How can I subset data frames from `ls1` which contain exactly 3 columns?**

I tried this

```
lapply(ls1, subset, ncol = 3)
```

but it doesn't work.. thanks !!

Comment: Subset doesn't have an ncol argument. You cannot just make up arguments and expect R to interpret them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls1[sapply(ls1,ncol) == 3]
```

or

```
Filter(function(x) ncol(x) == 3, ls1)
```